# ImageView- cannot find image by id

Tags: java, android

It seems that when I try to set the id of an image in an ImageView, I get an error

`imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);`

*error at "R.id.image1"

and when I look in R.java, the image names I put in res are in drawable class and not in id class.

```
public static final class drawable {
        public static final int image1=0x7f020011;
        public static final int image2=0x7f020012;
        public static final int image3=0x7f020013;
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020017;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int button1=0x7f080002;
        public static final int button2=0x7f080003;
        public static final int button3=0x7f080004;
        public static final int button4=0x7f080005;
        public static final int imageView1=0x7f080001;
    }
```

but when I put "R.drawable.image1" it seem to work fine but R.id is necessary to avoid any future errors. What seems to be the problem? And how do I fix it? I cannot seem to find any related posts.

Comment: check if it is android.R??? it should be package.R OR there must be some error in res folder clean once ur project

Comment: Post your full activity class including imports

Comment: you are using activity or fragment?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `findViewById()`, which searches the View hierarchy for a View object with the id you provide.

The `image1` ID that you are trying to find in `R` is actually the ID of a drawable. You cannot search for a View by the ID of it's drawable- you can only search for a View by that View's ID.

Judging from the other IDs present in your `R`, what you really want to do is call `findViewById(R.id.imageView1);`.

`R.drawable.image1` can be used to reference the drawable, for example if you want to set a View's background to that drawable.

`R.id.imageView1` can be used to reference the ImageView in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add it as drawable

```
imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView1.setResourceDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
```